# как получить название основного браузер python

Tags: python, браузер

Я пишу программу которая будет искать информацию в 2 режимах.

Инкогнито и Обычный.
Код который я нашёл:

```
os.system("Start-Process chrome.exe -ArgumentList @( '-incognito', 'www.foo.com' )")
```

*Работает. Но мне нужно получить название основного браузера. Будь то Opera или FireFox или пусть даже Edgle.*

Как желательно без помощи сторонних модулей получить название браузера установленного по умолчанию.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2178637/5308259 Только непонятно, зачем это нужно в контексте вопроса.

Comment: код, который вы нашли, не имеет никакого отношения к вашему вопросу.

Comment: @strawdog как раз имеет. Вместе chrome я буду запусукать браузер по умолчанию

Comment: Еще раз. код в вашем вопросе не имеет отношения к вопросу. зачем вы привели код запуска браузера, а спрашиваете совсем про другое?

Comment: Мне нужно для этого кода название браузера получить @strawdog

Comment: А для чего вам нужно название браузера?

Comment: @NickolayChistov чтоб из powershell и не только можно было вызвать инкогнито режим

Answer (score 1):

Возможность открытия сайта, браузером по-умолчанию, доступна из коробки через [webbrowser.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open)

Пример:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('www.foo.com')
```

---

У `webbroser` есть метод для получения стандартного браузера, но у меня поля этого браузера возвращали пустые строки ([и тут в комментах написали, что на линуксе с этим проблем нет](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60907297/5909792)):

```
import webbrowser
print(webbrowser.get().name)
print(webbrowser.get().basename)
```

Поэтому, [ищем решение для windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12444963/5909792):

- В реестре по пути `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.html\UserChoice\Progid` имя класса
- В `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<class>\shell\open\command` путь до exe

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/1d5a6a5b502ac79fada17d6b2ec663d035df5d38/winreg__examples/get_default_browser.py#L10)

```
from winreg import OpenKey, HKEY_CURRENT_USER, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, QueryValueEx


def get_browser_command() -> str:
    path = r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.html\UserChoice"
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, path) as key:
        browser_id = QueryValueEx(key, 'Progid')[0]

    path = browser_id + r"\shell\open\command"
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, path) as key:
        command = QueryValueEx(key, '')[0]

    return command


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_browser_command())
    # "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -osint -url "%1"
```

Comment: Это конечно прикольно. Но цель моя была в том чтобы запустить вкладку в режиме инкогнито

Comment: Да и + если пользователь не выбрал браузер по умолчанию будет ошибка

Comment: В таком случае, вариантов кроме ручного запуска exe браузера с передачей ему параметров я не знаю... Браузер, по умолчанию, можно в реестре найти, для windows. Обновил ответ